# PHP post server - how does posttestserver.com work?

Tags: php, post

I am trying to build a post server similar to posttestserver.com and have been runnning into lots of trouble.

The following returns nothing -

```
do {
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
} while (empty($data));

header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');
header('Content-Type: text/html');

var_dump($data);
```

I have also had a look into the use of sockets but the client should be directed to a URL rather than an ip/port for the clients ease. I suspect that this is what i need to use but am not sure where to start.

For what its worth, the client expects an HTTP 2XX response code from its HTTP POST request, and the client will not attempt submitting the next HTTP POST request while a previous request is still in flight.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does "This doesnt work" mean _exactly_? Or are we meant to guess that?

Comment: Hi arkascha, thanks for the reply. What i meant was that it is not capturing any of the POST data at all.

Comment: If `$_POST` does not hold any data, then no http post data has been provided.

Comment: The client is sending data. When i point it to posttestserver.com it is sending and receiving fine. However, when i change the URL to my test script it produces nothing.

Comment: Nothing more I can say. My above comment is true. Maybe you rewrite the incoming request somehow, but those are things we cannot tell you. It is _your_ system, only you have access.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you cannot capture and view the POST data in the one browser window.

For what its worth, here is the code that worked in the end -

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
//do something with the data such as write to file or database
```

Then you could use the data in another PHP script.